# Rspec "valid_session" confusion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Im just learning how to do Rspec controller/integration tests, and I noticed a lot of examples I see look something like so:

```
let(:valid_attributes) { { name: 'John Doe', age: 32, title: 'Manager', startData: Time.now } }

let(:valid_session) { {} }
```

then something like:

```
  describe "POST #create" do
    it "create user" do
      post :create, params: {:valid_attribute}, session: valid_session
      expect(response).to redirect_to login_url
    end
  end
```

Is this correct? The Middle portion is whatever `params` are getting passed right? (Where `:valid_attribute` is called? A lot of times I see on `get` requests where that is blank? Im assuming passing a param on a get request would just append it to the url like `/login/?=something`

Either way my questions were:

1. In the middle where the params are defined (I assume) do I need to name the model? IE: should it be  `params: {:valid_attribute}` or `params:{:user :valid_attribute}`
2. Im a bit confused on why I see `session` defined especially when it's just blank? Im assuming this would be if we needed to pass some session token to say that a "test user" is logged in...but why are we passing a blank one? (I see this on a lot of examples)

If there is a more proper way to write these, let me know. Im just now diving into them!

Thanks

As a sidenote I see different forms of `get` or `post`. Sometimes it will be `get '/index'` but then sometimes it's `get :index`. Which is the correct way? Im assuming rspec matches the symbol for the controller test to the actual controller action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I always remove those from newly generated specs and write the data I want to send into each and every get/post in the spec. And it's `valid_attribute` without the `:`. Think of `let` as a sort of method you call.

```
post :create, params: {user: {email: 'tom@example.com'}}
get :index
get :index, params: {email: 'example.com', active: true}
```

The session part, well, that's if you don't use something like the test helpers from devise but you roll your own. You will barely ever need it so just remove it.

`get '/index'` and `get :index` should be equal but I prefer the `:index` and so does the [rspec documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs).